# React-Native: TouchableOpacity not working for Absolute in Android

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Sorry i have been trying to fix this for quite a while but can't figure out :(
I'm unable to get the touchableopacity below to work for Android. It works fine for IOS.

Based on my search it seems that absolute and touchableopacity don't work well together (probably zindex issues). When i remove all the absolutes its perfect.

I've looked at the other StackOverflows, but couldn't get a good answer.

```
  <View style={{ position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>

   <TouchableOpacity
  onPress={()=>{
    console.log("move next tapped");
  }}>
  <View style={{ position: 'absolute', left: wp('90%'), top: wp('50%')}}>

  <MaterialIcon
  name="arrow-right-bold-circle"
  size={25}
  color="#828282"
  />
  </View>
  </TouchableOpacity> 

</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok quite stupid i solved it. Just moved the View out of the touchableopacity.

```
<View style={{ position: 'absolute', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
      <View style={{ position: 'absolute', left: wp('90%'), top: wp('50%')}}>

      <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={()=>{
        console.log("move next tapped");

      }}>


      <MaterialIcon
      name="arrow-right-bold-circle"
      size={25}
      color="#828282"
      />

      </TouchableOpacity> 

      </View>

   </View>
```